# Road network per grid cell with weighting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, road

Im trying to calculate road network per grid cell.

I did it with the help of [Measure length within vector grid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64688/measure-length-within-vector-grid) & [Calculate line distances inside of polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/calculate-line-distances-inside-of-polygons-using-arcgis-for-desktop/98521#98521) but I am also trying to weight these roads by type.

For example, if road is main its impact should be high, but if road is secondary it will be lower. Is this possible?

Comment: What precisely have you tried from those earlier Q&As and your own efforts, and where did you get stuck?